# Getting incorrect json format

Tags: json, swift

I am trying to print some json connected with urlLink and getting "The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format." Below is the code . Not sure what i am doing wrong especially with json serialization:

```
guard let url = URL(string: "http://localhost/DataDog/registering.php") else {
                return
            }
            
            var request = URLRequest(url: url)
            
            request.httpMethod = "POST"
            
            let body = "username=\(usernameTxt.text!.lowercased())&password=\(passwordTXT.text!)&email=\(emailTxt.text!)&fullname=\(nameTxt.text!)%20\(surnameTxt.text!)"
            
            
            request.httpBody = body.data(using: .utf8)
           
            print(body)
            print("HPPBODY")
            print(request.httpBody!)
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
                
                if error == nil {
                    
                    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                            
                        do {
                          
                            if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? NSMutableDictionary {
                               
                                if let names = json["id"] as? String {
                                    print(names)
                                }
                            }
                        } catch let error as NSError {
                            print("Failed to load: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                        }
            
                        
                    })
                    
                } else {

                    print(error!)

                }
            }.resume()
```

Json from url is below:

```
{"status":"200","message":"Succesfully registered","id":"45","username":"adonosisossmahasss","email":"mm@gmsil.com","fullname":"bey mahat","ava":""}
```

Comment: `print("Failed to load: \(error.localizedDescription)")` -> `print("Failed to load: \(error)")`, what does it says now? Also, the JSON you gave is from where? From where did you get it? I don't see a `print("Received response: \(String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)!)")`, as it could be different because your request is wrong.

Comment: try to print the `data` object before calling `JSONSerialization.jsonObject`, and compare with string you expect (maybe response isn't was you expect).

Comment: Yes i printed: This is the response "Failed to load: The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format."

Comment: Isn't that the print of `error.localizedDescription` instead of `error`?

Comment: This is the new error with no localizedDescripion: ""JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set. around line 1, column 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set. around line 1, column 0., NSJSONSerializationErrorIndex=0}"

Comment: Could you give the output of `print("Received response: \(String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)!)")`? Does it seems to be the expected JSON?

Comment: Part of the problem is `as? NSMutableDictionary`. You'll get an `NSDictionary`. If you want a mutable one, you need to use `mutableCopy`.

Comment: In fact, you should use `[String: Any]`, that' be better, but shouldn't trigger a thrown error. Even more, using `Codable` would be better.

Comment: Yes . i made the mistake . doing [String: Any] worked. Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

Create Codable Struct as

```
struct JsonResponse:Codable {
    let status:String?
    let message:String?
    let id:String?
    let username:String?
    let email:String?
    let fullname:String?
    let ava:String?
    
}
```

Use JSONDecoder to decode response as

```
if let jsonData = try? JSONDecoder().decode(JsonResponse.self, from: data) {
print(jsonData)
}
```